# ActiveRecordでgroupしたクエリを集計してviewに表示する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

著者(`Author`)毎に記事(`Article`)をグループ化し、
それを記事一覧に 記事数として表示しようとしています。

`記事一覧`
|著者ID|著者名|記事数|
|-----|----------|--------|
|       1|  AAA|       1|
|       2|  BBB|      10|
|       3|  CCC|       5|

`ArticlesController`

```
  @articles = Article.all.group(:author_id)
  ~~~ 略 ~~~
  @articles = @aticles.page(params[:page]).per(20))
```

`index.html.erb`

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= article.author.id %></td>
    <td><%= article.author.name %></td>
    <td><%= article.???????????? %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

記事のグループ化は出来たのですが、記事数を表示する方法がわかりません。
`Article.all.group(:author_id).count`のように`.count`を使ってみましたが
著者IDと記事数のハッシュが返って来てしまうため その後のページネイションがうまく行かなくなります。

また、`.sum`で集計するカラムはスキーマに追加していません ex) `.sum(:amount)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Railsの機能の[カウンターキャッシュ](http://railsdoc.com/references/counter_cache)を使うと良いと思います。

```
# モデル作成
$ rails g model Author name articles_count:integer
$ rails g model Article author:belongs_to

# model
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, counter_cache: true
end

# controller
@authors = Author.includes(:articles).all

# view
<% @authors.each do |author| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= author.id %></td>
    <td><%= author.name %></td>
    <td><%= author.articles_count %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

上のようなカラムを持つ Author を作成すると、articles を追加するたびに articles の count 数が Author のレコードに保存されます。集約した記事数を検索する場合は、Author の articles_count を検索すれば良いでしょう。

`rails c`での実行結果。Article の INSERT と同時に、Author の UPDATE が行われています。

```
pry(main)> Author.first.articles.create
  Author Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `authors`.* FROM `authors`  ORDER BY `authors`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `articles` (`author_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, '2015-05-22 21:31:21', '2015-05-22 21:31:21')
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `authors` SET `articles_count` = COALESCE(`articles_count`, 0) + 1 WHERE `authors`.`id` = 1
   (9.1ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: counter_cache初めて知りました!
今回の案件は処理数が多かったため 
別トランザクションで管理する https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture にしました! ありがとうございます!

Answer (score 1):

表示する内容からして著者一覧を取得して表示すれば良いのではないでしょうか？

```
# model
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  ...
end

# controller
@authors = Author.includes(:articles).all
...

# view
<% @authors.each do |author| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= author.id %></td>
    <td><%= author.name %></td>
    <td><%= author.articles.size %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
今回は 集約した記事数を検索対象にしたいということもあり `Article`をベースに考えております。。 `.size`便利ですね!!

Answer (score 0):

次のように `select` を指定すると特異メソッド `count` が定義されます。

```
@articles = Article.group(:author_id).select("*, count(id) AS count")
```

これは次のようなSQL文を生成します。

```
SELECT *, count(id) AS count FROM "articles" GROUP BY author_id
```

あとは、Viewで

```
article.count
```

とすることで値を得られます。

Comment: このSQLはMySQLでは通るかもしれませんが、Postgresqlではエラーになると思いますよ。group byに含まれてないものをselectしているので。

http://qiita.com/YusukeHigaki/items/6c1330867ba788a210c8
http://vividcode.hatenablog.com/entry/sql/mysql-groupby-nonaggregated

MySQLでは通りますが、意図した結果が返ってこない可能性があります。

Comment: なるほど!!
`.select`を使ったところ確かに上記のSQLが発行され、
そのSQLをconsoleで実行すると `AS count`の値が確認できました。

しかしActiveRecordでは
`=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Article id: 1, author_id: 1, name: "記事1", ~~~  deleted_at: nil>`
となり`count`が入っていないようで、viewからも`article.count`を参照できませんでした。

何かModel側に設定は必要でしょうか。(mysqlを使っています)

Comment: `count` は表示されなくてもアクセス出来るはずです。`@articles.map { |a| [a.author, a.count] }` などを試してみてください。
(取得する際には、`@articles = Article.group(:author_id).select("author_id, count(author_id) AS count")` とでもした方が良いかもしれません。)